# What is the database schema of a one-to-one relationship involving a weak entity set?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, database-schema

Here's my problem:

A "LoanRequest" becomes a "Loan" on approval.

[image]

Here, there will be 2 tables: LoanRequest & Loan

The key for LoanRequest is

```
 {RequestDate, Borrower}
```

Considering that "Loan" is a weak entity set, the key for Loan should be `{ApprovalDate, Borrower, RequestDate}`, however, a key is what determines the rest of the attributes of the entity. So, here, `{RequestDate, Borrower}` can alone determine "Loan", then why should `{ApprovalDate, Borrower, RequestDate}` be the key?

Also, why can we not consider Loan "is a" LoanRequest, since Loan is actually an approved loan request? 
[image]

Comment: *"A 'LoanRequest' becomes a 'Loan' on approval."* If you're going to be a steely-eyed database dude, you have to stop talking like that.  A loan request doesn't cease to exist when it's approved. A loan request is one thing; an approved loan request is another thing, regardless of what you call it.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably this is not a (mandatory) 1-1 relationship because not all Loan Requests are also Approved Loans? I expect the relationship is 1 - 0/1.

If it is truly a business rule that a borrower can only request one loan per day then it seems that {Borrower, RequestDate} is a candidate key of both a loan and an approved loan. If {Borrower, RequestDate} is a candidate key then {ApprovalDate, Borrower, RequestDate} cannot also be a key - keys must be irreducible.

Write down the fact types and the business rules you intend to represent by your data model. It seems like you are getting bogged down in the limitations of an ER diagram before you've worked out what you want the diagram to show.

Answer (score 2):

You are over-thinking this and that will usually send you down the wrong path.

1. A loan doesn't exist without an approval date.  So, how can the borrower and request date tell you anything about a non-existent loan?  Good piece for a key don't you think?
2. A loan request is not a loan, its a request.  They have different attributes and they serve two different purposes in the business.

Comment: Yeah... so, would the key for Loan Request be {RequestDate, Borrower} or {ApprovalDate, Borrower, RequestDate}? I am confused because according to @sqlvogel {RequestDate, Borrower} will be the key for both, Loan and LoanRequest. But you said that, "how can the borrower and request date tell you anything about a non-existent loan"?